# Techniques for increasing arithmetic intensity of elementwise CUDA kernel

Tags: python, cuda, cupy

I have written a CUDA kernel for calculating pairwise interactions between a set of source particles and target particles.

My M target particles look like,

```
[[x_1,y_1,z_1],...,[x_m, y_m, z_m]]
```

And my N source particles look like

```
[[x_1,y_1,z_1],...,[x_n, y_n, z_n]]
```

with M < N.

I begin by transferring all source/target data to the GPU, and looping through batches of the source particles and evaluating the pairwise interactions with *all* targets.

Like so (in cupy syntax)

```py
for i in range(n_blocks):
    left_idx = i*width
    right_idx = (i+1)*width
    gpu_func(
       grid_dimensions, block_dimensions, targets, 
       sources[left_idx:right_idx,:], width
    )
```

where `sources` and `targets` are arrays on the GPU containing the source and target data.

My question is what do I have to do to avoid this loop? I am a novice to CUDA. My thinking is to check whether the global thread indices from each thread satisfy the 'left_idx' and 'right_index' conditions I've got above in my host device loop, is this correct? Is there a better way of doing this? I feel like I'm massively underutilising the GPU currently as the number of sources/targets is significantly less than the number of CUDA cores on my machine for my problem.

Comment: Suggesting how to increasing the arithmetic intensity of a kernel requires knowledge of the kernel. A one sentence description of the kernel is insufficient to provide such suggestions. Code matters

Answer (score -2):

> My question is what do I have to do to avoid this loop? I am a novice to CUDA.

A basic notion in parallel programming - CUDA or otherwise - is that instead of looping, which happens serially in time, you let different processing elements / threads / automatons / whatever work on all "loop iterations" in parallel: N processing elements do 1 piece of work each, rather than 1 processing element doing N pieces of work using a loop.

In CUDA, and in your case with M and N, that could mean having a 2D grid of M x N, with each CUDA thread working on one pair of source and target particle sets. Or a smaller grid, with each CUDA threads running a loop over several pairs, but less pairs.

You may remember the CUDA vectorAdd example, which computes an elementwise addition of two vectors. Here's a possible kernel for it:

```
__global__ void vecAdd(int *A, int *B, int *C, int N)
{
   int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
   C[i] = A[i] + B[i]; 
}
```

you see? No loops whatsoever. It's the multitude of threads in the grid that ensure that every possible i - between 0 and N-1 - has the corresponding element of C computed.